# Pass the "name" text in option to php form

Tags: php, html, post

Is there a way to pass the text in the name of the `<option>` to a php from?

```
<form action="process.php" method="post">
<select name="select1">
    <option value="1" name="apple">APPLE</option>
    <option value="2" name="lemon">LEMON</option>
    <option value="3" name="grapes">GRAPES</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

I want to get the fruits name in simple or capital passed to the php from.

I cannot change the values in the select tag because they are used for another function.

I've searched so many sites but all they say is about passing the text of the value, but not the text of the name.

Comment: jquery can help you...

Comment: _I cannot change the values in the select tag because they are used for another function._ So you're doomed.

Comment: The `value` attribute is submitted in a standard form submission. There are no non-standard form submission options. So: no. Either change the `value`, or figure out that `1` equals "apple" on your server.

Comment: Using javascript you can get the text

Comment: or `value="1|apple"` and then do an `explode("|", $_POST['select1']);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no attribute **name** in `<option>` tag

My Code:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="process.php" method="post">
<select name="select1" id="select1">
    <option value="1" name="apple">APPLE</option>
    <option value="2" name="lemon">LEMON</option>
    <option value="3" name="grapes">GRAPES</option>
</select>
<input type="hidden" id="hidField" name="xyz" value="" />
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
<script>
//function test(){
    var select1= document.getElementById("select1");
    $("#select1").change(function(){
      //alert(select1.options[select1.selectedIndex].text);
      //alert(select1.options[select1.selectedIndex].getAttribute("name"));
      var res=select1.options[select1.selectedIndex].getAttribute("name");
      document.getElementById('hidField').value=res;   //Javascript code
      //$('#hidField').val(res);  //Jquery code
      return false;
    });
//}
</script>
```

If you are sure want to **name** field is must there please use `getAttribue("name")` instead of `text`

Code:

```
alert(select1.options[select1.selectedIndex].getAttribute("name"));
```

Want to get inner data of the `<option>` tag

Code:

```
alert(select1.options[select1.selectedIndex].text);
```

Comment: is there a way to pass the selected alerted value to a hidden field?

Comment: may i know how that done as i'm not an experienced in changing values using java-script

Comment: yes hidden value is passed hidden field is not showing in url.  Please make some changes in your code. Please use onchange event in jquey `$("#select1").change(function(){` //Code here   });

Comment: tried that way but still the same :/ code screen shot [link](http://t.co/pSyl31pEOF)

Comment: I am checking above code in my local system. it is working perfect.

Comment: Hey @Isuru i saw your screenshot pleaser remove alert. Please Look my code again... `var res=select1.options[select1.selectedIndex].getAttribute("name");`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41959/discussion-between-chinmay-sahu-and-isuru)

Answer (score 1):

You pass the name-Attributes in a separate function with AJAX. All you have to do is to add an ID-Attribute (e.g. "select1") to the select Tag and read out the "textContent" attribute (Fruits in capital letters) of the selected option. Then pass the function "sendToServer" to the "onchange" event of the select-tag.

```
function sendToServer()
  {
    var select = document.getElementById("select1");
    var sel = select.options[select.selectedIndex];
    var name = select.getAttribute("textContent");

    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
        {

        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "../PHPScripts/getData.php?q=name", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
  }
```

HTML:

```
<select name="select1" id="select" onchange="sendToServer();">
  <option value="1" name="apple">APPLE</option>
  <option value="2" name="lemon">LEMON</option>
  <option value="3" name="grapes">GRAPES</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

I know, its not exactly what you asked for, but maybe it helps.

Comment: Note that an independent AJAX request may greatly complicate the architecture here. It's not exactly the same as submitting the value in the same POST request.